# Crop out partial image using NumPy (or SciPy)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Using `numpy` or `scipy` (I am not using `OpenCV`) I am trying to crop a region out of an image.

For instance, I have this:

[image]

and I want to get this:

[image]

Is there something like `cropPolygon(image, vertices=[(1,2),(3,4)...])` with `numpy` or `SciPy`?

Comment: is it just for plotting purposes? or do you want to actually process only a part of your data, which is the interesting part of an image?

Comment: I only want to process that region of the image

Comment: Not for plotting purposes

Comment: what i did was make a 1D array with all values of the points which are within a region (determining that region was by geographical coordinates, rather complicated in my case), and than another array in which the row/col index of these pixels were put, and than process it further like that, but depending on the final application, that may be a good or bad tactic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you using matplotlib?

One approach I've taken previously is to use the `.contains_points()` method of a `matplotlib.path.Path` to construct a boolean mask, which can then be used to index into the image array.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.path import Path
from scipy.misc import lena

img = lena()

# vertices of the cropping polygon
xc = np.array([219.5, 284.8, 340.8, 363.5, 342.2, 308.8, 236.8, 214.2])
yc = np.array([284.8, 220.8, 203.5, 252.8, 328.8, 386.2, 382.2, 328.8])
xycrop = np.vstack((xc, yc)).T

# xy coordinates for each pixel in the image
nr, nc = img.shape
ygrid, xgrid = np.mgrid[:nr, :nc]
xypix = np.vstack((xgrid.ravel(), ygrid.ravel())).T

# construct a Path from the vertices
pth = Path(xycrop, closed=False)

# test which pixels fall within the path
mask = pth.contains_points(xypix)

# reshape to the same size as the image
mask = mask.reshape(img.shape)

# create a masked array
masked = np.ma.masked_array(img, ~mask)

# if you want to get rid of the blank space above and below the cropped
# region, use the min and max x, y values of the cropping polygon:

xmin, xmax = int(xc.min()), int(np.ceil(xc.max()))
ymin, ymax = int(yc.min()), int(np.ceil(yc.max()))
trimmed = masked[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
```

Plotting:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)

ax[0,0].imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[0,0].set_title('original')
ax[0,1].imshow(mask, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[0,1].set_title('mask')
ax[1,0].imshow(masked, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[1,0].set_title('masked original')
ax[1,1].imshow(trimmed, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[1,1].set_title('trimmed original')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this method still contain data about the original image? It's weird because when I perform `scikit-image` analysis on the image the areas which I have cropped out are still being analyzed.

Comment: `masked` is a [`np.ma.masked_array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html). Whether or not the masked areas are analyzed will depend on the behavior of the particular function in question. Most basic numpy operations (`np.sum`, `np.max` etc.) will ignore the masked values. You can use the boolean mask in many other ways - for example you could get a 1D array containing just the pixel values in the cropped region using `img[mask]`, or you could set values outside this region to NaN using `img[~mask] = np.nan`.

Comment: Hmm is there a way to convert the masked array to a normal array?

Comment: Read the link I posted - a masked array consists of the original array of values, plus the mask. You can access the original values through the `.data` attribute, and the mask through the `.mask` attribute. What exactly do you mean by "convert"? What do you want to happen to the values outside of the mask region?

Comment: I just need the polygon region to perform image analysis on. I would like just the numpy.array containing this region, nothing else.

Comment: I'm using scikit-image functions on the image

Comment: The `data` attribute returns what I have given it. I just want the polygon region.

Comment: For example, I am subtracting one mask from another to view motion.

Comment: Then don't you already have what you want? The boolean array called `mask` is `True` only within the polygon crop region.

Comment: If I take masked_array_1 - masked_array_2, for some reason, it will return an image containing the difference between the normal images

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46962/discussion-between-ali-m-and-high-schooler)

Comment: I actually found a way around this. I used matplotlib's path module instead!

Comment: @Highschooler yes, that's exactly what my answer uses

Comment: @Highschooler can you explain your way around this in more detail? I'm running into a similar problem where I'd like to use skimage.filters.threshold_otsu on a numpy masked array.