# Point inside polygon

Tags: numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a way to determine whether a particular point is within a polygon given its vertices using NumPy/SciPy.

I haven't been able to find one online. Is there even a way to do this using NumPy/SciPy?

Comment: You've already asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21566610/1461210). If you're not satisfied with the answer I gave you, you should unaccept it and comment to explain why, rather than opening another question.

Comment: Not the sane question, last one was about cropping this is about point in polygon.

Comment: The basic underlying question is the same - your 'crop' region is a polygon, you want to index points that fall within the polygon. Both arkottke's answer and mine address this.

Comment: Different problems however

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you considered [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely)? Just create a [Polygon](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#polygons) and check if polygon [contains](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#binary-predicates) a point.

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point
>>> from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

>>> point = Point(0.5, 0.5)
>>> polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
>>> polygon.contains(point)
True
>>> point2 = Point((10, 10))
>>> polygon.contains(point2)
False
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting! Though I was hoping that numpy/scipy would have something to do this rather than installing a new module. 

By the way: Do you know of any tools that would allow me to draw vertices on an image?

Comment: @Highschooler I would use the image as a backgroun on matplotlib figure and then use the [event handling](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) to pick points.

Comment: Shapely unfortunately doesn't come with pip `pip installs shapely`  :(

Comment: @user1767754 it does now, only apparently not for windows
https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/

Answer (score 0):

scikit-image (`skimage`) is maintained by the same community as SciPy, and has this method available: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.points_in_poly

Usage and small example:

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import points_in_poly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]])
poly = np.array([[0.5, 0.5], [1.5, 0.5], [1.5, 1.5], [0.5, 1.5]])
poly_to_plot = np.vstack([poly, poly[0]])

is_in_poly = points_in_poly(points, poly)
for ii in range(len(points)):
    plt.scatter(*points[ii], color="blue" if is_in_poly[ii] else "black")
plt.plot(*poly_to_plot.T, color="red")

plt.show()
```

[image]