# Updating DataFrame in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with spatial data in Python Pandas. I have two dataframes that represent two distinct business entities - transactions and locations (sizes of 10^6 and 420). I am trying to map transaction to specific location by updating transactions dataframe.
Is there a better way to do that than what I am doing in simple nested for loop?! I tried using k-d and r trees but these are hard to implement. On the other hand, simple nested for loop takes ages to complete.
This is my code for nested for loop:

```
    for parkomatIndex, parkomatRow in parkomats.iterrows():
        if (parkomatRow["area"] == ""):
            if (pointInPolygon(round(float(parkomatRow["lon"]), 6), round(float(parkomatRow["lat"]), 6), parkingZonePolygon)):
                parkomats.ix[parkomatIndex, "area"] = index
```

Function to resolve whether point is in polygon (used function from http://www.ariel.com.au/a/python-point-int-poly.html)

```
def pointInPolygon(x,y,poly):

n = int(len(poly[0]))
inside = False

p1x = round(float(poly[1][0].replace(",", ".")), 6)
p1y = round(float(poly[0][1].replace(",", ".")), 6)

for i in range(n+1):
    p2x = round(float(poly[1][i % n].replace(",", ".")), 6)
    p2y = round(float(poly[0][i % n].replace(",", ".")), 6)

    if y > min(p1y,p2y):
        if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
            if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
                if p1y != p2y:
                    xints = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
                if p1x == p2x or x <= xints:
                    inside = not inside
    p1x = p2x
    p1y = p2y

return inside
```

Comment: You could try using shapely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612976/point-inside-polygon

Comment: Or you could try using geopandas: http://geopandas.org/

Comment: My concern however is that I also update the dataframe in the process which is pretty slow (as it contains aforementioned 10m rows). Maybe I should try different approach (i.e. create a new mapping list/dataframe) as I guess that updating a dataframe is the bottleneck in the process. Also maybe there's a smarter way how to optimize a closest point search rather than to reiterate through points over and over again?