# Is it possible to select data in a plot with python and remove data selected?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Hello i did a python file which allows to select datas thanks to creating a polygon and then i would like to delete the points inside the polygon. This is my code :

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
#from matplotlib.widgets import Button

a = np.array([1,2,3,5,7])
b = np.array([1,6,5,7,9])
plt.plot(a,b, '.')
myList=[]

class Canvas(object):
    def __init__(self,ax):
        self.ax = ax

        # Create handle for a path of connected points
        self.path, = ax.plot([],[],'o-',lw=3)
        self.vert = []
        self.ax.set_title('LEFT: new point, MIDDLE: delete last point, RIGHT: close polygon')

        self.x = [] 
        self.y = []

        self.mouse_button = {1: self._add_point, 2: self._delete_point, 3: self._close_polygon}

    def set_location(self,event):
        if event.inaxes:
            self.x = event.xdata
            self.y = event.ydata

    def _add_point(self):
        self.vert.append((self.x,self.y))

    def _delete_point(self):
        if len(self.vert)>0:
            self.vert.pop()

    def _close_polygon(self):
        self.vert.append(self.vert[0])
        for i in range(0,a.size):
            myList.append(Point(a[i],b[i]))
        polygon = Polygon(self.vert)
        for i1 in range(0,a.size):
            if polygon.contains(myList[i1]):
                global a,b
                a = np.delete(a,i1)
                b = np.delete(b,i1)
        plt.plot(a,b, 'g.')





    def update_path(self,event):

        # If the mouse pointer is not on the canvas, ignore buttons
        if not event.inaxes: return

        # Do whichever action correspond to the mouse button clicked
        self.mouse_button[event.button]()

        x = [self.vert[k][0] for k in range(len(self.vert))]
        y = [self.vert[k][1] for k in range(len(self.vert))]
        self.path.set_data(x,y)
        plt.draw()
if __name__ == '__main__':

    fig = plt.figure(1,(8,8))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    cnv = Canvas(ax)

    plt.connect('button_press_event',cnv.update_path)
    plt.connect('motion_notify_event',cnv.set_location)

class Index(object):
    ind = 0

    def next(self, event):
        plt.draw()

    def prev(self, event):
        plt.draw()

callback = Index()


plt.show()
```

But i have two problems : firstly i don't know why but the points inside the polygon stay in the figure. And then, the points inside the polygon become green whereas they are not outside the polygon. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21613346/7207392) might help?

Comment: Thank you but what i want now is to be able to remove this points :)