# How can I determine if a point is inside a certain parallelogram in Python?

Tags: python, math, geometry

I'd like to know how to determine if two points d1(920, 52.1), d2(920, 52) are inside of this orange parallelogram, which is comprised of p1~p4.

[image]

As you can see, the base of the parallelogram is not parellel to x-axis.

Are there any modules that deal with this kind problems? Or I'd like to get some math help in this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? To horizontal part of the calculation should be rather simple to do.

Comment: You can calculate triangles areas to the given number, if the area of the paralellogram is bigger than the sum of the triangled areas, than it's inside.

Comment: Are you allowed to use any library. This would make your life easier.

Comment: @Klaus D Thank you for the comment. I thought calculating angles of the line of x=52 and lines of p1-d1, p1-d2 might have some clues, but then it got too complicated and now I'm looking for better ways to solve this problem. Would you please explain more about it to me?

Comment: @user1767754  Thank you for your idea! Do you have any library that you recommend I use?

Comment: This guy basically creates a shape with shapely.This would require you to install shapely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612976/point-inside-polygon btw. your p4, and p3 coordinates y axis are missing

Comment: And we are basically looking for some code from you that shows you put some effort into it already. We are not going to do all the work for you.

Comment: @ user1767754 Thank you again for the link. I've solved my problem! Actually, the coordinates are offered by a graphic library(pyqtgraph) and it doesn't give you every coordinate of the 4 points.

Comment: @ Klaus D Thank you. I will keep that in mind and add some of what I have tried next time.

Comment: Hi maynull, the etiquette here is _not_ to add "solved" to the title of a question, so I've reverted that edit. Instead, you should accept the answer that worked for you. In this case, since nobody else has posted an answer, you should post one yourself that explains the solution to your problem, and accept that. Write your answer in a way that will be useful for future people who are reading this because they have a similar problem.

Comment: @ David Z Thank you for telling me the etiquette! I posted how I solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parallelogram there is approach simpler than for general polygons. Get coordinates of three neighbor vertices in order c, a, b and represent `AP` vector in basis of `AB` and `AC` vectors - coefficients should be in range `0..1`.

Note that Delphi and Python function use different argument order. In Delphi base point (a) goes first, then its neighbors (b, c), while Python list contains c,a,b (or b,a,c) points in order.

Delphi code:

```
function PtInPlgm(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, px, py: Integer): Boolean;
var
  xb, yb, xc, yc, xp, yp, d: Integer;
  bb, cc, oned: Double;
begin
  Result := False;
  xb := bx - ax;
  yb := by - ay;
  xc := cx - ax;
  yc := cy - ay;
  xp := px - ax;
  yp := py - ay;
  d := xb * yc - yb * xc;
  if d <> 0 then begin
    oned := 1 / d;
    bb := (xp * yc - xc * yp) * oned;
    cc := (xb * yp - xp * yb) * oned;
    Result := (bb >= 0) and (cc >= 0) and (bb <= 1) and (cc <= 1);
  end;
end;
```

Literal Python [translation](https://ideone.com/nRAose):

```
def point_inside_prlgm(x,y,poly):
    inside = False
    xb = poly[0][0] - poly[1][0]
    yb = poly[0][1] - poly[1][1]
    xc = poly[2][0] - poly[1][0]
    yc = poly[2][1] - poly[1][1]
    xp = x - poly[1][0]
    yp = y - poly[1][1]
    d = xb * yc - yb * xc;
    if (d <> 0):
        oned = 1.0 / d;
        bb = (xp * yc - xc * yp) * oned
        cc = (xb * yp - xp * yb) * oned
        inside = (bb >= 0) & (cc >= 0) & (bb <= 1) & (cc <= 1)
    return inside

    print(point_inside_prlgm(1, 1, [[1, 2], [0, 0], [2, 0]]))
    print(point_inside_prlgm(-1, 1, [[2, 1], [0, 0], [2, 0]]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's an interesting way to solve the problem! I will work on it! Have a good weekend!

Comment: I made Python function with your prototype

Comment: The solution isn't correct. Test for example with the three vertices (-1,-1), (-1, 2), (2, 3) and a sample point (0,0) which is inside that parallelogram. The function returns False.

Comment: @Mads Boyd-Madsen Just checked -returns true:  https://ideone.com/McU0cX

Comment: What am I doing wrong I wonder... Let me try again ... I'm doing: PtInPlgm( -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0 ), and that returns False. I copied your function into Delphi's editor as is. I also stepped through it to see what happens. d is -9 and then oned is -0.1111111, which in turn cause bb to be -0.111111 and the function returns False. I think I'm getting that right

Comment: There is another solution to the problem which use a simplified version of the quadrant walk algorithm. It should also be one of the fastest implementations as it only use subtraction, increment by one, and boolean comparisons. I will write an answer for that once I get a moment. I'm no Python shark though.

Comment: @Mads Boyd-Madsen I understood - Delphi points go in another order than Python ones. Base point first, then two its neighbors. Perhaps I have to clarify this moment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159887/discussion-between-mads-boyd-madsen-and-mbo).

Answer (score 1):

The following solution use the quadrant walk algorithm optimised for parallelograms. It is a derivative of the winding-number algorithm.

That algorithm place the test-point P at the centre of a coordinate system and walks the vertices of the polygon in order, checking for "positive and negative axis-crossings". If the number of axis-crossing is a multiplum of 4 (but not 0), then P is inside the polygon. Intuitively P is inside the polygon, if walking the vertices "cross all four half-axis". Hence the multiplum of 4.

The algorithm can be highly optimised (especially well suited for assembler implementation) and **run fast**.

Here it is in Delphi, using the same parameter order as the function **PtInPlgm** given in the answer by MBo

```
function PtInPlgm2( bx, by, ax, ay, cx, cy, px, py: double ): boolean;
var
  Sum    : integer;
  dx, dy : double;

begin
  Sum := 0;
  dx := cx - bx + ax;
  dy := cy - by + ay;
  if ( px < ax ) <> ( px < bx ) then inc( Sum );
  if ( py < ay ) <> ( py < by ) then inc( Sum );
  if ( px < bx ) <> ( px < cx ) then inc( Sum );
  if ( py < by ) <> ( py < cy ) then inc( Sum );
  if ( px < cx ) <> ( px < dx ) then inc( Sum );
  if ( py < cy ) <> ( py < dy ) then inc( Sum );
  if ( px < dx ) <> ( px < ax ) then inc( Sum );
  if ( py < dy ) <> ( py < ay ) then inc( Sum );
  Result := (Sum mod 4 = 0) AND (Sum <> 0);
end;
```

I trust it's Ok, that I haven't provided a Python implementation

Comment: O, I see - this is method of projection of point onto axial projections of edges. Are six checks from eight possible enough?

Comment: Yes - because the question asked for a parallelogram with two rectilinear edges. I've updated the answer to highlight that point. Otherwise you are right - would need eight checks.

Comment: Algorithm is good, but question does not define specific kind of parallelogram - note that sides are slightly inclined.

Comment: Yeh - I see what you mean. I'll add the extra two checks and remove comment

Comment: OK. Let's make algo perfect :) Point (0,0) in ((0,1),(1,0),(0,-1),(-1,0)) gives Sum=8.

Comment: Yes - I see what you mean. Thanks for spotting. The original algorithm asks for any sum which is a mulitplum of 4, I suppose. I've update the answer

Comment: Some cases when function fails: `146 148 116 102 90 96 60 50 125 138; 94 156 172 100 78 134 156 78 96 110` ax ay bx by cx cy dx dy px py (dx, dy calculated for reference). Code to test and draw fault cases:https://ideone.com/n0TPTu

Comment: Right Ok :-) :-) - I'll go back to the original algorithm and optimise properly - one more time - for a parallelogram. Will take me a wee while ...

Comment: Could you show comprehensive description of this algorithm?

Comment: This algorithm (as I am reading it) is incorrect. Consider the points (0, 0), (1, 1), (5, 2) and (6, 3). The point (3, 2.5) isn't in the parallelogram, but  the sum is 4 because (1,1)x < (3, 2.5)x while (6,3)x > (3, 2.5)x, (5, 2)x > (3, 2.5)x while (0,0)x < (3, 2.5)x, (1,1)y < (3, 2.5)y while (6,3)y > (3, 2.5)y and (6, 3)y > (3, 2.5)y while (5, 2)y < (3, 2.5)y

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Shapely, but I read that it's realatively slow. My program needs to use the logic at least 100 times a minute, so I look the keywords up on the internet and found this page: http://www.ariel.com.au/a/python-point-int-poly.html

```
# determine if a point is inside a given polygon or not
# Polygon is a list of (x,y) pairs.

def point_inside_polygon(x,y,poly):

    n = len(poly)
    inside =False

    p1x,p1y = poly[0]
    for i in range(n+1):
        p2x,p2y = poly[i % n]
        if y > min(p1y,p2y):
            if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
                if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
                    if p1y != p2y:
                        xinters = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
                    if p1x == p2x or x <= xinters:
                        inside = not inside
        p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y

    return inside
```

It works fast enough and doesn't require additional modules. I think coding this code in C and using it in Python could be a good idea.