# easy way of getting RGB from 2D image cells within set of points

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, python-imaging-library

I was wondering if there is an easy way of copying all of the 2D cells from an image, that is between a set of points.

So, for example imagine there is a 2D image. I place a triangle anywhere over this image and extract only the part of the image that is inside of the triangle.

I'm hoping there is an easy way to do this without having to create a confusing  algorithm.

[image: Example 2D image and points to cut-out]

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890051/how-do-i-generate-circular-thumbnails-with-pil

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21567205/1461210