# How to fill numpy array of zeros with ones given indices/coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Given a numpy array of zeros, say

```
arr = np.zeros((5, 5))
```

and an array of indices that represent vertices of a polygon, say

```
verts = np.array([[0, 2], [2, 0], [2, 4]])
```

1) What is the elegant way of doing

```
for v in verts:
    arr[v[0], v[1]] = 1
```

such that the resulting array is

```
In [108]: arr
Out[108]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

2) How can I fill the array with ones such that the output array is

```
In [158]: arr
Out[158]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question: `arr[tuple(verts.T)] = 1`

`verts.T` transposes your indices to a `(2, n)` array, where the two rows correspond to the row and column dimensions of `arr`. These are then unpacked into a tuple of `(row_indices, col_indices)`, which we then use to index into `arr`.

We could write this a bit more verbosely as:

```
row_indices = verts[:, 0]
col_indices = verts[:, 1]
arr[row_indices, col_indices] = 1
```

---

For the second part, one method that will work for arbitrary polygons would be to use [`matplotlib.Path.contains_points`](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.contains_points), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21567205/1461210):

```
from matplotlib.path import Path

points = np.indices(arr.shape).reshape(2, -1).T
path = Path(verts)
mask = path.contains_points(points, radius=1e-9)
mask = mask.reshape(arr.shape).astype(arr.dtype)

print(repr(mask))
# array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Shouldn't `mask[2,0]` be 1?

Comment: @DSM I think it's a floating point issue - a workaround is to set `radius` to a small positive value

Comment: Is there also a way to generate the array without giving it a name? At the moment, `arr=np.zeros(...); arr[([...],[...])]=1` is two statements. Can this be done in one line?