# How to efficiently set 1-D numpy array of zeroes to ones given a list of index ranges

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a list of ranges of indices I'd like to set to the same value in a 1-D numpy array.

For example, consider this list of index ranges:

```
[(0,1), (3,8), (9,11)]
```

I'd like my zero-ed array to look like this if I set the values to 1:

```
[1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
```

I'd like to do it as efficiently as possible, preferably without a for loop. Existing posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72081231/how-to-fill-numpy-array-of-zeros-with-ones-given-index-ranges-slices) do this for a 2-D array using broadcasting but it was not clear how to adapt it to 1-D.

For example, this works:

```py
indices_range_list = [(0,1), (3,8), (9,11)]
my_array = np.zeros(15)
for r in indices_range_list:
   my_array[r[0]:r[1]] = 1
print(my_array)
```

Output:

```py
array([1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran timeit and it seems none of the proposed solutions is faster than the for loop:

---

```
python3 -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; ind_ranges = [(0,1), (3,8), (9,11)]; arr = np.zeros(15)' 'np.put(arr, np.r_[*[slice(*r) for r in ind_ranges]], 1)'
```

50000 loops, best of 5: 5.93 usec per loop

```
python3 -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; ind_ranges = [(0,1), (3,8), (9,11)]; arr = np.zeros(15)' 'for s,e in ind_ranges: arr[s:e] = 1'
```

500000 loops, best of 5: 542 nsec per loop

---

So it seems the for loop is the most efficient, at least in these simple tests. Again, that's:

```
import numpy as np
ind_ranges = [(0,1), (3,8), (9,11)]
arr = np.zeros(15)
for s,e in ind_ranges:
    arr[s:e] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can index all the necessary indices by creating a list of all the indices within the given ranges and then use that list for indexing.

```py
my_array = np.zeros(15)
indices = np.hstack([np.arange(*vals) for vals in indices_range_list])
my_array[indices] = 1
print(my_array)
```

Output:

```py
[1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Even though this doesn't loop over the main array, it is slower than the original code because building the `indices` array takes time.

Answer (score 0):

With [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)(to translate slice objects to concatenation) + [`np.put`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) routines:

```
ind_ranges = [(0,1), (3,8), (9,11)]
arr = np.zeros(15)
np.put(arr, np.r_[*[slice(*r) for r in ind_ranges]], 1)
```

Final `arr`:

---

```
array([1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code? There is a syntax error, though I do not immediately see the issue.

Comment: @jared, I would not posted it without running without errors

Comment: As is, your code does not run due to a syntax error. That's just an observation.

Comment: @jared, It's running without any issues on `numpy=1.24.3`

Comment: I think it's a python version issue, gives syntax errors in 3.9.15 & 3.10.10 but works in 3.11.3 - ```np.put(arr, np.r_[(*[slice(*r) for r in ind_ranges],)], 1)``` works with all 3 mentioned versions

Comment: @Nin17 That might explain it. I'm on 3.10.11.

Comment: I ran timeit and unfortunately, this is much slower than the for loop: 
python3 -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; ind_ranges = [(0,1), (3,8), (9,11)]; arr = np.zeros(15)' 'np.put(arr, np.r_[*[slice(*r) for r in ind_ranges]], 1)'
50000 loops, best of 5: 5.93 usec per loop

python3 -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; ind_ranges = [(0,1), (3,8), (9,11)]; arr = np.zeros(15)' 'for s,e in ind_ranges: arr[s:e] = 1'
500000 loops, best of 5: 542 nsec per loop