# Numpy: how to create a mask (0, 1) of a 2D matrix having left and right limits of reach row?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I'm trying to generate a mask matrix having indepented slices for each row. Starting from a 0 matrix, I want to put a 1 at different slices of each row. The only solution I found is to use a `for` loop to loop through the slice list and apply it to the corresponding row. Can this be done without a `for` loop?

See the example below:

```py
mask = np.zeros((3, 3))
slices = [
[0, 2], # row 0, from [0:2] = 1
[1, 3], # row 1, from [1:3] = 1
[0, 1]  # row 2, from [0:1] = 1
]

for row, (x0, x1) in enumerate(slices):
    mask[row, x0:x1] = 1
```

I want to obtain the following mask without iterating on the slices

```
[[1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to efficiently set 1-D numpy array of zeroes to ones given a list of index ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76723435/how-to-efficiently-set-1-d-numpy-array-of-zeroes-to-ones-given-a-list-of-index-r)